# how to include iframe in Angular 2?

Tags: angular

I want to redirect to a link which generates the HTML, on click of a tab in Angular 2.0. I have currently coded like this.

```
  import { Component, Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
    import { DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser';


    @Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: 'my-pictures',
    template:'
    <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
    <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" width="300" height="100"            [src]="'https://www.youtube.com/embed/CM6rVEAAQ3k' | safe" allowfullscreen>   </iframe>
    </div>
  `,
})


@Pipe({ name: 'safe' })
export class PicturesComponent implements PipeTransform {
    constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) { }
    transform(url) {
        return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(url);
    }
}
```

It says Parameter 'url' implicitly has an 'any' type. Please let me know what's wrong in my current code. Also, guide what is the correct way to include iframe in Angular 2.

Comment: What about `transform(url) :SafeResourceUrl { ...`

Comment: Still the issue remains Same.

Comment: constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) { }
    transform(url): SafeResourceUrl {
        return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(url);
    }

Comment: Didn't read properly. The error message is about `url`. Use `transform(url:string) : SafeResourceUrl {`

Comment: I am getting the below mentioned message in console.

Comment: Unhandled Promise rejection: Template parse errors:
The pipe 'safe' could not be found ("nsive embed-responsive-16by9">
      <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" width="300" height="100" [ERROR ->][src]="'https://www.youtube.com/embed/CM6rVEAAQ3k' | safe" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </div>
 //<h"): PicturesComponent@6:69
The pipe 'safe' could not be found ("
    </div>
 //<h1>{{title}}</h1>
 // <iframe id="iframeId" [ERROR ->][src]="'https://www.youtube.com/embed/CM6rVEAAQ3k' | safe"></iframe>

Comment: "): PicturesComponent@9:26 ; Zone: <root> ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: SyntaxError {_nativeError: Error: Template parse errors:
The pipe 'safe' could not be found ("nsive embed-responsive-16by9">
  …} Error: Template parse errors:
The pipe 'safe' could not be found ("nsive embed-responsive-16by9">
      <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" width="300" height="100" [ERROR ->][src]="'https://www.youtube.com/embed/CM6rVEAAQ3k' | safe" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </div>
 //<h"): PicturesComponent@6:69
The pipe 'safe' could not be found ("
    </div>

Comment: You should give your pipe a proper nsame and then add it to `declarations: [...]` in `@NgModule(...)`

Comment: I tried giving various names, the problem still remains same. Can you please provide code for this.

Comment: @Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: 'my-pictures',
    template: `  
<iframe [src]="embedUrl" allowfullscreen></iframe>   
 `,
})
export class PicturesComponent {
    embedUrl = '';
    constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {
        this.embedUrl = 
            this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl('https://www.youtube.com/embed/2a4Uxdy9TQY\');
    }
}

Comment: I changed as mentioned above, but now it says Type 'SafeUrl' is not assignable to type 'string' for this.embedUrl.

Comment: Can somebody please help me with the correct way of including iframes in Angular 2 with an example.